# Understanding PCI-Express

Tags: hardware, pci

I already know that a PCI-E has lanes( which depend on x1, x4, etc... ) which consist of 2 wires. One wire receives while the other transmits. Each wire can transfer 1-bit each cycle simultaneously. However, the lane is a full-duplex system.

I need clarification from you guys. Is this information correct?

Comment: From a programming viewpoint, none of this is relevant at all -- even to the (few) programmers who write things like device drivers, PCI-E still follows the same model as PCI and PCI-X.

Comment: So is this information correct or not?

Comment: Let me try to be more clear: You're asking in the wrong place. The topic here is *programming*. Something like this that has zero effect on programming belongs somewhere else.

Comment: Hmmmm...All right then. Thanks Jerry.

Comment: There are quite a few places devoted to hardware (e.g., TomsHardware.com, lostcircuits.com). If you like the SO "vibe", you might want to commit to the Computer Hardware proposal on Aread 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4239/computer-hardware

Answer (score 3):

Each lane built from Rx and Tx directions. Each direction has a differential pair which means 4 wires for each lane.

Each Rx\Tx lane can transfer 1bit each cycle.